# How to remove all borders in table?

Tags: html, css

Heres my code:

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border: none;">
            <td colspan="12" align="center">2012</td>
            <td colspan="12" align="center">2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px;border: none;">Ene</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 29px;border: none;">Feb</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Mar</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Abr</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">May</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Jun</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Jul</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Ago</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Sep</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Oct</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Nov</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Dic</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Ene</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 28px">Feb</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Mar</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Abr</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">May</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Jun</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Jul</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Ago</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Sep</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Oct</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 30px">Nov</td>
            <td align="center" style="width: 31px">Dic</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #000;border: none;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="background-color: #000;border: none;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GWj3w/2/

As you can see I set the border in the table to 0 and also the style for the tr and td tags to border: none but I still get that white line between cells, also in the style I put

```
* {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

How can I remove this border??

Thanks!!

Comment: Those aren't borders, they're gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the spaces by using either (note: there is a slight [difference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders) between the two)

`border-spacing: 0;` or `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GWj3w/1/

Comment: Yeap this does it...THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix! set cellpadding and cellspacing to 0 on your table element.  All that border adjustments can be confusing, plus you don't need to control `<tr>` border adjustments.  keep it simple :)

Comment: It is specifically `cellspacing=0` (a more robust alternative than using CSS, but frowned upon by many as a matter of principle) that removes the gap, which is *not* a border. The question does not really have anything to do with border adjustments (tables have no borders by default).

Comment: Correct, its removing space not a border.